# How to check if an NSMutableAttributedString font size is smaller/greater than some value?

Tags: swift, font-size, nsmutableattributedstring

I try to make an if block by checking if an NSMutableAttributedString font size is smaller/greater than some value. I couldn't find an explanation about this. Code sample is as follows:

```
if textView.font.pointSize < 30 {
   //execute
}
```

where string inside textView is `NSMutableAttributedString`. Any ideas?

Comment: In a NSAttributedString you can have multiple sizes. So if you want to check the sizes, you need to enumerate (like your previous question to change it). Instead of changint it like before, just keep the size, and get the max one or something like that?

Comment: @Larme Thank you Larme, I didn't think about that. I then try different methods. You are really helpful programmer, I really appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but that should do the trick

```
extension UITextView {
    func maxPointSize() -> CGFloat {
        var max: CGFloat = font?.pointSize ?? 0.0 //In case you mix .attributedText and .text but I'd recommand to avoid mixing them.
        guard let attributedString = attributedText else { return max }
        attributedString.enumerateAttribute(.font, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length), options: []) { value, range, pointee in
            guard let font = value as? UIFont else { return }
            max = font.pointSize > max ? font.pointSize : max
        }
        return max
    }
}
```

The idea is to enumerate the fonts inside the `NSAttributedString`, and keep the max value.

Then

```
if textView.maxPointSize() < 30 {
   //execute
}
```